# configurar correctamente el dominio de videos e imagenes para que carguen correctamente

Tags: laravel, hosting

He estado trabajando en local con un proyecto laravel donde he subido fotos y videos.

Ahora lo he subido a un hosting y no me cargan las fotos porque aparacen con la direccion del anterior dominio. ¿Como podría cambiarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué dominio tienes declarado en el archivo `.env` (`APP_URL`)?

Comment: Lo normal es que las url's de las imagenes o videos que hayas subido se guarden en alguna tabla de la base de datos o en algun sitio. Donde lo guardas modifica la url y ya esta. Para la proxima vez personalmente yo recomiendo en vez de guardar la url del dominio guarda la direccion absolute de la raiz hacia la carpeta donde esta el archivo sin el dominio asi si cambias de host siempre te funcionara.

Comment: en el archivo .env tengo APP_URL=https://amigosurf.com

Comment: Y cómo cargas las fotos? Agrega toda la información a la pregunta